# No bytecode,no ABI code showed in the Remix

Tags: remix

Sir,
   I use Remix to developing smart contracts. After I develop one contract ,I  prepare to copy the bytecode or ABI code. I click the Details button,the Remix doesn't show the bytecode or ABI code information. This works before,but not works now . I use JavaScript VM and Solidity version is 0.4.4.

[image: no bytecode/ABI code information]

How to solve this problem?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Click 'Details' (in your picture)

Then click the copy icon for the ABI (interface).  You'll just be able to copy it and then paste it somewhere else (it won't show since its too long)

Comment: I solve this problem.Change the solidity version to 0.4.7 or above ,including my code and the Remix setting.When I click the Details button,Remix popup the Detail window. I don't know the reason,but it works.